# How do I remove the posterize filter from the rest of the elements in my p5js sketch?

Tags: javascript, filter, processing, p5.js, posterization

I'm new to p5js, and I'm having troubles with removing the posterize filter from the rest of the elements in my sketch (I would like to have it just applied to "image(capture, 0, 0)")

Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
let delay = 1000;
let capture;
let angle = 0;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("mask.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1280, 720);

  // Create an audio input to record the sounds from the microphone
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  // start the Audio Input
  mic.start();

  // Creating an FFT object to get the sound frequency
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  fft.setInput(mic);

  // Capture video
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.size(320, 220);
  capture.hide();
}

function draw() {
  
  // Inserting the video
  push();

  // Move the origin from (0,0) to the center of the canvas
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  imageMode(CENTER);

  // Setting rotation angle
  rotate(angle);
  
  
  // Inserting the video 
  image(capture, 0, 0);
  
  // !! HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO APPLY THE FILTER !!
  filter(POSTERIZE, 3);
  
  // Increase the rotation angle
  angle += 0.03;
  
  pop();
  
  // !!FROM HERE I WOULD LIKE THE FILTER TO DISAPPEAR!!
  // Creating the video mask
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(img, width / 2, height / 2, width, height);

  // Drawing empty vynil
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 10);
  noFill();
  stroke(200);
  strokeWeight(3);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 660);

  // Creating variables to store the level of mic and of frequency
  let vol = mic.getLevel();
  let spectrum = fft.analyze();

  // Get the values of the frequencies
  let bass = fft.getEnergy("bass");
  let lowMid = fft.getEnergy("lowMid");
  let mid = fft.getEnergy("mid");
  let highMid = fft.getEnergy("highMid");

  // Map the frequencies to  use them for the circles' colour
  let hue1 = map(bass, 0, 255, -90, 370);
  let hue2 = map(lowMid, 0, 255, -75, 340);
  let hue3 = map(mid, 0, 255, -15, 315);
  let hue4 = map(highMid, 0, 255, 0, 85);

  // Map the volume to use it for the circles' stroke
  let circleStroke = map(vol, 0, 1, 1, 40);

  // Draw the circle with color based on the
  let numCircles = 16;
  for (let i = 1; i < numCircles; i++) {
    let diameter = i * 30 + 140; // Calculate the radius of each circle
    setTimeout(function () {
      // draw circles
      strokeWeight(circleStroke);
      stroke(hue1, hue2, hue3 + hue4);
      noFill();
      ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, diameter);
    }, 1000 * i);
  }
}
```

I've tried using resetMatrix(); and putting it between push() and pop(), but it seems not to work.

Comment: please reduce this to a [mcve]