# How to fix "glitching effect" in p5js sketch

Tags: debugging, p5.js, conflict

I'm creating a sketch in which circles are created based on the frequency and volume of sounds recorded by the microphone.

Here the code seems to work fine:

```
let delay = 1000;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("mask.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1280, 720);

  // Create an audio input to record the sounds from the microphone
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  // start the Audio Input
  mic.start();

  // Creating an FFT object to get the sound frequency
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  fft.setInput(mic);

function draw() {
 

  // Drawing empty vynil
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 10);
  noFill();
  stroke(200);
  strokeWeight(3);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 660);

  //creating variables to store the level of mic and of frequency
  let vol = mic.getLevel();
  let spectrum = fft.analyze();

  // Get the values of the frequencies
  let bass = fft.getEnergy("bass");
  let lowMid = fft.getEnergy("lowMid");
  let mid = fft.getEnergy("mid");
  let highMid = fft.getEnergy("highMid");

  // Map the frequencies to  use them for the circles' colour
  let hue1 = map(bass, 0, 255, -90, 370);
  let hue2 = map(lowMid, 0, 255, -75, 340);
  let hue3 = map(mid, 0, 255, -15, 315);
  let hue4 = map(highMid, 0, 255, 0, 85);

  // Map the volume to use it for the circles' stroke
  let circleStroke = map(vol, 0, 1, 1, 40);

  // Draw the circle with color based on the
  let numCircles = 16;
  for (let i = 1; i < numCircles; i++) {
    let diameter = i * 30 + 140; // Calculate the radius of each circle
    setTimeout(function () {
      // draw circles
      strokeWeight(circleStroke);
      stroke(hue1, hue2, hue3 + hue4);
      noFill();
      ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, diameter);
    }, 1000 * i);
  }
}
```

However, when I add in the central part a video recording which rotates, the circles start to glitch:

```
let delay = 1000;
let capture;
let angle = 0;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("mask.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1280, 720);

  // Create an audio input to record the sounds from the microphone
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  // start the Audio Input
  mic.start();

  // Creating an FFT object to get the sound frequency
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  fft.setInput(mic);

  // Capture video
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.size(320, 220);
  capture.hide();
}

function draw() {
  //THIS IS THE PART THAT IS APPARENTLY CAUSING ISSUES TO THE CODE
  // Inserting the video
  push();

  // Move the origin from (0,0) to the center of the canvas
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  imageMode(CENTER);

  // Setting rotation angle
  rotate(angle);
  
  
  // Inserting the video 
  image(capture, 0, 0);
  
  // Increase the rotation angle
  angle += 0.03;
  
  pop();
  
  // Creating the video mask
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(img, width / 2, height / 2, width, height);

  

  // Drawing empty vynil
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 10);
  noFill();
  stroke(200);
  strokeWeight(3);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 660);

  //creating variables to store the level of mic and of frequency
  let vol = mic.getLevel();
  let spectrum = fft.analyze();

  // Get the values of the frequencies
  let bass = fft.getEnergy("bass");
  let lowMid = fft.getEnergy("lowMid");
  let mid = fft.getEnergy("mid");
  let highMid = fft.getEnergy("highMid");

  // Map the frequencies to  use them for the circles' colour
  let hue1 = map(bass, 0, 255, -90, 370);
  let hue2 = map(lowMid, 0, 255, -75, 340);
  let hue3 = map(mid, 0, 255, -15, 315);
  let hue4 = map(highMid, 0, 255, 0, 85);

  // Map the volume to use it for the circles' stroke
  let circleStroke = map(vol, 0, 1, 1, 40);

  // Draw the circle with color based on the
  let numCircles = 16;
  for (let i = 1; i < numCircles; i++) {
    let diameter = i * 30 + 140; // Calculate the radius of each circle
    setTimeout(function () {
      // draw circles
      strokeWeight(circleStroke);
      stroke(hue1, hue2, hue3 + hue4);
      noFill();
      ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, diameter);
    }, 1000 * i);
  }
```

Do you think this issue could be solved or is it a conflict between the different elements into the code?

Comment: Your snippets are missing a few closing `}` to be able to run the code. Can you clarify what effect you're trying to achieve ? the `setTimeout` section in particular is confusing: I suspect this is what is causing flickering/glitchy looking rendering. (Try commenting the `setTimeout` line and ` }, 1000 * i);` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76361517/how-do-i-remove-the-posterize-filter-from-the-rest-of-the-elements-in-my-p5js-sk) looks similar: is this coursework ?